# Accept classroom invitation from script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I wrote a simple script that create classrooms from a spreadsheet, all the classrooms are owned by me and after I invite a teacher in each class with his email address.
That is the code that create the classroom

```
function creaClassi(infoClasse) {
  let corso = Classroom.newCourse();
  corso.ownerId = "me";
  corso.name = infoClasse.name;
  corso.section = infoClasse.section;
  Classroom.Courses.create(corso);
}
```

The code works well, I create the class, no errors. The classroom is created in my account, but I have to "Accept" the classroom, I mean that if I open the classroom page I see all the classrooms I create with the buttons "Refuse" and "Accept".

First question: why I have to accept the classrooms that I create?

Ok, I tried to accept the classroom with this:

```
Classroom.Invitations.accept(https://classroom.google.com/c/MzEyNjI3MzEwNjgx)
```

But doesn't work, I found in classroom API that I should use the invitation link, but I can't find where to catch the invitation link.

Second question: How to accept all the classroom I create with the script or in a bulk?

Comment: `Classroom.Invitations.accept` accepts invitations that are created via `Classroom.Invitations.create` and accepts an object as its argument containing the `id`, not the link from `Classroom.Courses.create`. They are different instances. As for the first question, I have scoured the net and wasn't able to find the reason why the classrooms you created need to be accepted by you manually.

Comment: Thank you NaziA, waiting for someone that can answer about my first question.

Comment: Creating classrooms may be designed to be accepted manually as we don't want to have notifications by default to all the classrooms we created. Someone can create the classroom but doesn't automatically join that classroom, unless manually joined/accepted the invite. This may pertain to something that happens in real life where the departments of the school decides what courses to offer, not the actual teachers/professors. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that make sense, but in this case it happens that I create classrooms with owner "me" and I have to accept them. After that I create teacher classroom  with the statement    Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create({userId: infoInvito.teacher}, infoInvito.classroom_Id);  and the teacher that receive the classroom as invited teacher is not required to accept the classroom.